# Django server does not start locally when APScheduler is added to models.py

Tags: python, django

For some reason, `python manage.py runserver 8000` does start up the server whenever I include the add the following code to my app's **models.py** file:

```
def tick():
    print('Tick! The time is: %s' % datetime.now())

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(tick, 'interval', seconds=3)
scheduler.start()

try:
    # This is here to simulate application activity (which keeps the main thread alive).
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    # Not strictly necessary if daemonic mode is enabled but should be done if possible
    scheduler.shutdown()
```

Instead, I get the following output:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.1\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Python27\python.exe D:/blogpodapi/manage.py runserver 8000
Tick! The time is: 2016-08-14 20:55:15.993000
Tick! The time is: 2016-08-14 20:55:18.993000
Tick! The time is: 2016-08-14 20:55:21.995000
Tick! The time is: 2016-08-14 20:55:24.994000
Tick! The time is: 2016-08-14 20:55:27.997000
Tick! The time is: 2016-08-14 20:55:30.995000
Tick! The time is: 2016-08-14 20:55:33.994000
Tick! The time is: 2016-08-14 20:55:36.994000
```

The expected output should be as below, followed by the output of the script above:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.1\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Python27\python.exe D:/blogpodapi/manage.py runserver 8000
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 14, 2016 - 14:00:32
Django version 1.9.6, using settings 'blogpodapi.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

The entirety of the models.py file can be found here: http://pastebin.com/SwvZju84.

Comment: What are you expecting? You've added an infinite loop right in the middle of Django's startup cycle, how would it continue past that loop to get to the rest of the code?

Comment: @knbk I'd like the task to run periodically after Django's startup cycle. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure it is, but you can't block the main thread with an infinite loop if you still want Django to run.

Comment: @knbk Can you please help me understand how to do it. I've been struggling for a couple days. I presume it involves starting the task in a new thread but I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

Comment: Well, you've started the scheduler with `scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(); scheduler.start()`. Now all you need to do is not block up the main thread executing Django, which you're doing with `while True: time.sleep(2)`. That should work fine enough for development.

Comment: @knbk can you show me an code sample of how to do that

Comment: Just remove the infinite loop, the `while True: time.sleep(2)` statement that's blocking up execution in the main thread and keeping the Django server from running properly. I'm not sure what else to say.